# Is it possible to zoom in/out the text editor in Xcode 9.1 using the trackpad?

Tags: xcode, fonts, zooming, trackpad

I'm editing a simple python script in Xcode.

When using TextEdit, I can zoom in/out using the trackpad by pinching with two fingers.

Can a similar behaviour be achieved in Xcode without using:
 **cmd+** or **cmd-**
?